# Replace Text inside a Text file

Tags: c#, text, c#-4.0, replace

I am trying to edit my text file with a `btn_click`. I can get it to read and print back to the text file but its not doing what I want. I Want to Change the Text after the = Example: `firebill=A`

I get `firebill=AF firebill=AFG firebill=AFGR` etc.., I add \r\n to my code and the get it drop a line Example: `firebill=R G F A` etc...

Here is the code I`m using.

```
        private void Btn1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        { 

        {

                ///\n\r
                /// Replaces text in a file.

                string filePath = @"D:\test.txt";               
                string searchText = "firebill=";
                string replaceText = "firebill=" + (txtb1.Text);

            

                    ReplaceInFile(filePath, searchText, replaceText);
            }

            void ReplaceInFile(string filePath, string searchText, string replaceText)
            {

                StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(filePath);
                string content = reader.ReadToEnd();
                reader.Close();

                content = Regex.Replace(content, searchText, replaceText);

                StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(filePath);
              
                writer.Write (content);
                writer.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: could you explain your example?

Comment: It's not clear what you expect your code to do. Could you add an example of a start and expected end result of the file content?

Comment: Well in my text file has like ,Fireball=D next line waterball=F I am trying to change the letter after = so Fireball=J

Comment: I add code to change fireball=U to now fireball=T 
but it shows fireball=T add again  fireball=TT add again fireball=TTT rewrites firebill= but not the letter

Answer (score 0):

Your regex pattern finds "`firebill=`" and replaces it with "`firebill=T`" (for example), this means that "`firebill=T`" will be replaced by "`firebill=TT`", because the "`firebill=`" at the start of the text matches your search pattern.
A correct regex pattern (i.e. 'searchText') would be "`firebill=[A-Z]+`", because the "`[A-Z]+`" would match whatever comes after the "=".